# Tomcat Compression Does Not Add a Content-Encoding: gzip in the Header

Tags: java, tomcat, gzip, yslow

I am using Tomcat to compress my HTML content like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxProcessors="150" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443"
acceptCount="150" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
compression="on" compressionMinSize="128" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType="text/html"
URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

In the HTTP header (as observed via YSlow), however, I am not seeing

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

resulting in a poor YSlow score.

All I see is

```
HeadersPost
Response Headers
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type:   text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language:   en-US
Content-Length: 5251
Date:   Sat, 14 Feb 2009 23:33:51 GMT
```

I am running an apache mod_jk Tomcat configuration.

How do I compress HTML content with Tomcat, and also have it add "Content-Encoding: gzip" in the header?

Comment: If you use mod_jk, don't you have to add that to the ajp connector, or did you also test directly on port 8080 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/.

Other custom solutions may have memory leaks.

Also, if you are using mod_jk then you are certainly not using the 8080 connector (which supports compression) for those requests.

Comment: cherouvim: Thanks. I will take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat will be doing the compression.  However because you are using `mod_jk` I guess you are getting you requests via Apache on port 80 rather than tomcat on port `8080`.  As an experiment try getting your page via port 8080 and then checking `yslow` you should see the correct headers.

I think what is happening is that apache is unzipping the content that it is getting from tomcat via `mod_jk` and then passing the deflated content on to the browser.

If you wish to use `mod_jk` then you will need to set up your compression on Apache rather than Tomcat.

Comment: AJP is a binary protocol anyway, so compression won't work on the AJP Connector. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol
I wouldn't recommend using the HTTP connector on a high-load production server anyway, regardless of compression being on/off.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the compression Tomcat is referring to isn't gzip? It's a stab in the dark, but it might relate to white-space compression, or line trimming.

I would imagine Tomcat would be a bit more explicit in this regard (here's hoping).

We have the gzip filter mentioned by duffmo running in our application, the web.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>App-Web</display-name>

    <!-- FILTERS -->

    <!-- Gzip filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>GZIPFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>weblogicx.servlet.gzip.filter.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    [snip]    
</web-app>
```

Comment: No, enabling compression in tomcat means gzip - it works fine for us under tomcat 6.0.20, though we do not have apache in front of our tomcat

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the Tomcat documentation here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

It mentions using `compression="force"`  which worked for me. It also says you can set a `minimum number`. This worked fine for me

```
<Connector port="8080" compression="256000" />
```

(compress anything over 256Kb)

The default value for `compressableMimeType` meant that I didn't need that attribute.
Also note that it doesn't list `CompressionMinSize` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To improve overall client side performance of J2EE web application, you can try WebUtilities java library.

> Here is the link :: http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/.

It provides filter, tag, servlet components to apply various client side performance practices resulting in higher performance rating against PageSpeed/YSlow.

Since version 0.0.4 it helps with following performance practices.

1. Minimize HTTP requests - can serve multiple JS/CSS files in one request
2. Client Side Caching - adds proper Cache-Control, Expires header
3. On the fly JS/CSS minification - using YUICompressor
4. Compression - supports 2way compression for gzip/deflate/compress encodings
5. Response Caching at Server - to avoid reprocessing of unchanged resources
6. Add Character Encoding - to let browser know in advance

It is also highly configurable/customization against MIME, URL or User-Agents.