# Cache image in browser

Tags: image, jsf, caching

I have a JSF page with very big images - 3.4 Mb. I use this code to call the image

```
<div data-src="resources/images/slide1.png">
```

Is there any way to cache the image into client browser because every time it takes 3-4 seconds to download the picture?

Comment: Why do you need 3.4MB slides? Thought of optimizing the images?

Comment: By default, everything obtained by a GET request is cached in the browser.
And images are loaded using GET :)

Comment: `png`'s are really bad for large images (such as photos)... consider using `jpg` format instead and you'll probably find the size of the image is just a fraction of the original

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF Cache Static Resources Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057932/jsf-cache-static-resources-filter)

Comment: @TheSM: that won't work if the resource is not referenced as a JSF resource.

Comment: @BalusC oh yes, you are so much right forgot about that glad you mentioned that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference it as JSF resource. Then JSF resource handler will automatically take care of caching. Its default expiration time is [configurable in `web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057932/jsf-cache-static-resources-filter).

So instead of

```
<div data-src="resources/images/slide1.png">
```

do

```
<div data-src="#{resource['images/slide1.png']}">
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)