# CacheControlFilter doesn't work on CSS background images

Tags: jsf, browser-cache, omnifaces

I'm using OmniFace 2.7 with Primefaces 6.0. I set with CacheControlFilter an expire time of 365d for all image types (`*.jpg` | `*.jpeg` | `*.png` | `*.gif` | `*.ico`).

This browser caching settings seem not to apply to CSS background images that get an URL like:

```
.../playground/javax.faces.resource/images/smiley.jpg.xhtml
```

Same apply to the combined resource files (CSS and JS) that have an URL like:

```
.../javax.faces.resource/LONG-HASH.js.jsf?ln=omnifaces.combined&v=1544138175000
```

Any hints to solve this issue would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Tried adding these 'composite extensions' as well?

Comment: How? That's why I'm asking.

Comment: That was not explicitly your question. But I have no idea. Did not use it myself (yet) How did you add the other extensions. Try it the same way

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CacheControlFilter) and [documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.7/org/omnifaces/filter/CacheControlFilter.html) of `CacheControlFilter`.

> **Important notice**: this filter automatically skips JSF resources, such as the ones served by `<h:outputScript>`, `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `@ResourceDependency`, etc. Their cache-related headers are namely [already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15057932/157882) controlled by the `ResourceHandler` implementation. In Mojarra and MyFaces, the default expiration time is 1 week (604800000 milliseconds), which can be configured by a `web.xml` context parameter with the following name and a value in milliseconds, e.g. `3628800000` for 6 weeks:
>
> - Mojarra: `com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge`
> - MyFaces: `org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES`
>
> It would not make sense to control their cache-related headers with this filter as they would be overridden anyway.

I don't have much to add on this.

Comment: Neither the defaultResourceMaxAge nor the ´CacheFilter´ option (see link from BalusC) affect the expiration of the 'composite extensions'. I tried both approaches. So there is no way to control it?.

Comment: I solved the problem with Nginx. Still find the restriction in JSF strange.