# Large component tree performance improvements

Tags: jsf-2, tree, components

I have a single page JSF application using tabbing that has a large component tree (approx 8400 nodes).  We are trying to get better performance out of it and are considering using iframes to break the component tree up into smaller trees (one for each tab) which I know has its own issues.  Is there any other alternative to this to prune the tree to a reasonable size other than a complete re-architecture?

Comment: what ARE the issues with a large component tree? Did you investigate with a phaselistener? Did you try using the execute attribute? Did you try using ajax? Your question is not so generic that it is hard to provide suggestions.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096202/jsf-performance-improvement. What jsf version and impl are you using?

Comment: When we load it with 50 users we see page response times of 15 to 20 seconds and cpu at 100% traced back to jsf render.  I have used a phaselistener to gather more statistics.  That is where I am getting the component tree numbers and render timing.  I am using jsf 2.0 and primefaces 3.5. We make extensive use of ajax and partial update it being a single page application.

Comment: _" That is where I am getting the component tree numbers and render timing."_ Please provide details... With just this we cannot start even trying to help. And are you sure it is not part of your code that is the cause of the problem? Tried a real profiler? With 'jsf render' you mean the JSF Render Phase?