# Performance improvement jsf

Tags: performance, jsf

I read about 2 parameters such as javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD =-1
     javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS=true can improve the performance.I tried those but i dont see any improvements is there anything i am missing or is there any better option which can achive the improvement.

Comment: 1: Where did you read this? Can you share a link? 2: About general performance things, your question is a duplicate with the same title, so stackoverflow must have suggested this to you to read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096202/jsf-performance-improvement

Comment: @Kukeltje: Below is the link http://jsfwarriors.blogspot.com/2015/06/jsf-application-performance.html

Comment: Just run a profiler to find the real performance problem. Here's at least an answer to #1 most common starter's mistake causing a JSF based webapp to apparently perform slowly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033

Answer (score 2):

You hardly see a performance improvement because the author of this blog highly exagerates when he/she states:

> we will talk about the most important aspects that can be tuned in order to enhance the
>   performance of JSF 2.x applications.

And adds the two you talk about as important ones without adding that at least the refresh period is highly related to load and has with java (n)io and way faster disks been optimized a lot.

#### javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD =-1

The OS IO layer caching in combination with the java nio and faster disks makes it really quick to check if a file timestamp, against which JSF checks for changes, has changed. This is so quick that you'll hardly notice any improvement these days. Maybe only a little when you have 1000's of simultaneous users. So yes, it helps, a little, but not as much as you'd expect from the wordings in the blog.

#### javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS=true

This would help if you have a comment to useful code ratio of 1:1, but you'll hardly have that much comment in the page so the gain of sending 100-500 bytes less in a 10k-100k page (all examples) is negligeable.

This setting is (at least for me) more usefull in that our internal comments in the page doe not end-up at the enduser.

#### For other improvements see

- [JSF Performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096202/jsf-performance-improvement))